# Calling Generic fields within a Singleton class

Tags: java, generics, jakarta-ee, singleton

I want to create a Singleton with generic class fields.

and use getter and setter for those fields for receiving the type. how can I do that ?

```
public class User<U,O> {

   private static final User instance;

   private U userId;
   private O organization;

   private User() {
   }

   public static synchronized User getInstance() {
        if(instance == null){User = new User();}
        return instance;
   }

   //getter and setter for U and O

}
```

how can I call the getter and setter outside the Singleton "by type" with no casting need ?

Comment: Do you want an instance for each combination of types?

Comment: @Bohemian This class will fetch inside many subsystem and the setters of the two fields will call only once at the starting point and is filled. I just need my getters to return the Generic Type as I pass it into my singleton method

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to type your `getInstance()`:

Try:

```
public class User<U,O> {

   private static final User<> instance;

   private U userId;
   private O organization;

   private User() {
   }

   public static <A, B> synchronized User<A, B> getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new User<>();
        }
        return instance;
   }

   //getter and setter for U and O

}
```